# Mouse movement opposite direction javascript

Tags: javascript, coordinates, mouse

So I'd like to have invert the x and y coordinates of the mouse, so that If I move, a div (that's going to be portfolio work in the end) will go towards the opposite direction.

I took this code (thank god) from an answer on this website. But I have a little issue, I cannot seem to enlarge the 'box' without it appearing in the left right corner. It's not working properly. If I move my mouse to the middle of the screen, the div is not op top of it. Which it should be. It works when I change the size of the box to 50px.

I also thought maybe the rest of my code kind of interrupted something and maybe could be the source of the issue. So that's why I included everything.

Hopefully some of you will give me a clue regarding what could be wrong!

```js
$(".book").click(function(){
      if ( $(this).hasClass('Offline') )   $(this).removeClass('Offline').addClass('Active');
      else    $(this).addClass('Offline')
})

$(".web").click(function(){
      if ( $(this).hasClass('Offline') )   $(this).removeClass('Offline').addClass('Active');
      else    $(this).addClass('Offline')
})




$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.fullcontain').on('mousemove', function(e) {
    var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    $('div.box').css({
      'right': x,
      'bottom': y
    });
  });
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p{
  color:white;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-family: times;
  font-weight: medium;
  font-size:20px;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  z-index: 1000;
}


body,html {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 26px;
}

.fullcontain{
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.container-menu{
  width: 25%;§
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  padding-top:20px;
}


.container-menu h5{
  color:black;
  padding-left:40px;
  padding-top:40px;

}

.container-content{
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  float:left;
}



.book{
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left:20px;
}

.bookinfo{
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left:20px;
}

.web{
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  padding-left:20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.webinfo{
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Active {
  height: 150px;
  transition: 1s linear;
}

.Offline {
  height: 20px;
  transition: 1s linear;
}

.box {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
  position: absolute;
  padding-right: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>

<div class="fullcontain">
    <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="container-menu">
  <p>Work<p>
    <div class="book Offline"><p>book</p>
      <div class="bookinfo">
        <p> #1 2018 Alice in Wonderland<br>
        <p> #2 2017 Two sides of a coin <br>
        <p> #3 2017 Timeline Memento<br>
        <p> #4 2018 Color book <br>
        <p> #5 2017 Archiving <br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="web Offline"><p>web</p>
      <div class="webinfo">
        <p> #7 2018 Research: becoming KIM K <br>
        <p> #8 2017 Interactive poster <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>










  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="index.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change you css to left and top.

```
$('div.box').css({
  'left': x,
  'top': y
});
```

This will work on opposite direction.

Btw, do you mean enlarge the 'box' to full screen? if so, you can set the css for the class .container-menu:

```
.container-menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    ...
}
```

Not sure this can help or not~